# Insert data from table to another table using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table which called `Logiciel` :

```
Name        Null?    Type
 ---------- -------- -------------
 NLOG       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)
 NOMLOG     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 DATEACH             DATE
 VERSION             VARCHAR2(7)
 TYPELOG             VARCHAR2(9)
 PRIX                NUMBER(6,2)
```

Using `PL/SQL` I want to add an entry which has the same data as the entry with `NLOG = 'log3'`, and the value PRIX as the average of `PRIX` : `AVG(PRIX)` of all entries.

This is the script I wrote:

```
DECLARE
    unLog LOGICIEL%ROWTYPE;
    moy LOGICIEL.PRIX%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT AVG(PRIX) INTO moy FROM LOGICIEL;
    SELECT * INTO unLog FROM LOGICIEL WHERE NLOG='log5';
    unLog.PRIX := moy;
    unLog.NLOG := 'logS';
    INSERT INTO LOGICIEL SELECT * FROM unLog;
END;
/
```

The problem is when I execute this script I get this error :

```
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 37:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 9, column 2:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `insert . .  . select`:

```
INSERT INTO LOGICIEL(NLOG, NOMLOG, DATEACH, VERSION, TYPELOG, PRIX)
    SELECT NLOG, NOMLOG, DATEACH, VERSION, TYPELOG,
           (SELECT AVG(PRIX) FROM LOGICIEL) as PRIX
    FROM LOGICIEL
    WHERE NLOG = 'log3';
```

EDIT:

Is this what you mean?

```
INSERT INTO LOGICIEL(NLOG, NOMLOG, DATEACH, VERSION, TYPELOG, PRIX)
    SELECT unlog.NLOG, unlog.NOMLOG, unlog.DATEACH, unlog.VERSION, unlog.TYPELOG, unlog.PRIX
    FROM dual;
```

Comment: I know about this method, but I've to work with PL/SQL

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU . . . Just insert this query between the `begin` and `end`.

Comment: What I mean is I've to do it using `%ROWTYPE` and `%TYPE`

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant, but why did you used that `dual` table ? why we can't just use the row `unlog` I've created

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU yes, one can finish the operator like VALUES(unlog.NLOG, unlog.NOMLOG, unlog.DATEACH, unlog.VERSION, unlog.TYPELOG, unlog.PRIX);

Comment: Why do you have to do it using %ROWTYPE and %TYPE? Gordon's answer is spot on, this is the right way to do it.